# Querying Terracotta

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, terracotta

Is there any way to Query against the objects stored by a Terracotta instance?

I am looking for SQL-Like Queries or any way to filter objects based on fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the enterprise version has its own search API:

http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/enterprise-ehcache/api-guide#enterprise-ehcache-search-api-for-clustered-caches

Answer (score 0):

JOSQL is iteration through all collection so if number of objects are large it could be slower.

You can read post http://tusharkhairnar.blogspot.com/2009/05/querying-java-objects-stored-in.html for implementing Indexing so that querying is fast.

There is tim-searchable released on forge site which has more features and uses Lucene framework.

Regards
Tushar